# SQL to fetch Unique values based on condition

Tags: sql

I have below data. The condition is that if the Id has two different types then take Long, such that there should not be any duplicate Id's

```
**id   type**
  1    Short          
  1    Long
  2    Short
  3    Short
  3    Long
  4    Short
```

And i need output like this.

```
 **id   type**
   1    Long
   2    Short
   3    Long
   4    Short
```

Comment: What type of SQL (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
select id, 
       case when count(id) > 1 then 'Long' else 'Short' end as type
from tmp 
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply take MIN from your Type column's value using GROUP BY on ID column. No CASE or COUNT statement is required. This following script will always work if you have specific value "short" and "long" in your column Type.

```
SELECT ID,MIN(Type) Type
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Select id, case when count(id)>1 then 'Long' else min(Type) End as Type
from Tbl 
group by id
```